# gettin play count for files played using mediaelement

Tags: audio, drupal-7, media, mediaelement.js

I am using mediaelement js module in drupal 7 to play an audio file. I need to track the no of times a file has been played.

Is there a module for solving my purpose? or can anyone help me about how to start with a custom module for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The [Download Count](http://drupal.org/project/download_count) module should so what you want, since playing a file is the same as downloading it.